# Generate Unique 6 Character alphanumeric string from a 10 Character alphanumeric string

Tags: java, serialization, unique

As the title suggests im trying to generate a unique 6 Character alphanumeric string from a 10 Character alphanumeric string.

Is there any algorithms people have used / can suggest for this? I using Java.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean exactly by "unique"? It is not possible to get a unique 6-character string for every possible 10-character string because of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). (There are many more possible 10-char strings than there are 6-char strings).

Answer (score 0):

You can use RandomStringUtils from apache `commons-lang3` [library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random-int-java.lang.String-).

```
RandomStringUtils.random(6,"ABCDEFGHIJ");
```

The caveat is in relation to the uniqueness. At some point they will be repeated since the possible set of results is limited.